# NinjaMyApp : What is FMNowAccountKey and how can i get it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Thanks in advance. I really very confused that how to implement NinjaMyApp into my app. I have account in ninjaMyApp but i do not know what to enter "Account Name:" in http://ninjamyapp.net/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you signed up for ninjamyapp you should get an email about filling out a survey. In the survey you create an account name. That account name you created is the one that you use to login.